# How to configure the shiny-server.conf?

Tags: r, shiny, time-series, shiny-server, shinyapps

I have installed a shiny server but I do not know how to connect my app to the server.
What I must change in the shiny-server.conf ?
[shiny-server.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKUyc.png)

Comment: Take look at this link https://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/ and consider using shinyproxy.